Keep always the last N values in an array and discard the oldest
I am writing a custom control that is basically a chart/graph that plots up to a maximum of 1024 double values.
I currently store the values in a List and when I get a new value over the 1024 count I Remove the last one on the list, and I am sure this is not the most efficient way of doing it, performance and allocation wise.
    private readonly List<double> myValues = new(1025);

    public void AddValue(double newValue) {
        myValues.Insert(0, newValue);
        if (myValues.Count > 1024) myValues.RemoveAt(1024);
    }

Is this the best/correct approach of doing it?
I am also considering using a straight double[] array and just copy the elements from 1 to -1 on each addition, but I got a feeling this is not correct neither.
    private readonly double[] myArray = new double[1024];

    public void AddValue2(double newValue) {
        Array.Copy(myArray, 0, myArray, 1, 1023);
        myArray[0] = newValue;
    }

Any suggestion or recommendation on what is the most efficient way of implement this?

Does this answer your question? Efficient way to implement an indexed queue (where elements can be retrieved by index in O(1) time)?

Keep track of your current index
https://dotnetfiddle.net/okZjRE

One efficient and easy way to implement this is to use an array with a front and a back index in order to implement a Circular Buffer.
The code is simplified if you make the underlying array one bigger than the maximum number of items that you want to store. This allows you to arrange things so that if the front_index == back_index then the buffer is empty.
Here's a sample implementation. It has methods to add an element, remove the oldest element, index elements from oldest to newest and enumerate elements from oldest to newest. Hopefully the code is fairly self-explanatory:
public sealed class CircularBuffer<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>
    /// <param name="capacity">The maximum capacity of the buffer.</param>
    public CircularBuffer(int capacity)
    {
        // We will use a buffer with a size one greater than the capacity.
        // The reason for this is to simplify the logic - we can use "front == back" to indicate an empty buffer.

        _buffer = new T[capacity + 1];
    }

    public int Capacity => _buffer.Length - 1;

    /// <summary>The number of elements currently stored in the buffer.</summary>
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int result = _back - _front;

            if (result < 0)
                result += _buffer.Length;

            return result;
        }
    }

    public bool IsEmpty => this.Count == 0;
    public bool IsFull  => nextSlot(_back) == _front;

    /// <summary>Removes all elements.</summary>
    public void Empty()
    {
        _front = _back = 0;
        Array.Clear(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length); // Destroy any old references so they can be GCed.
    }

    /// <summary>Add an element to the buffer, overwriting the oldest element if the buffer is full.</summary>
    /// <param name="newItem">The element to add.</param>
    public void Add(T newItem)
    {
        _buffer[_back] = newItem;
        _back = nextSlot(_back);

        if (_back != _front) // Buffer is not full?
            return;

        _front         = nextSlot(_front); // Bump the front, overwriting the current front.
        _buffer[_back] = default!;         // Remove the old front value.
    }

    /// <summary>Return the item at index, where 0 is the oldest thing in the buffer </summary>
    public T this[int index] => _buffer[(index + _front) % _buffer.Length];

    /// <summary>Removes and returns the oldest element from the buffer.</summary>
    /// <returns>The element that was removed from the buffer.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Thrown if the buffer is empty.</exception>

    public T RemoveOldestElement()
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot remove an element from an empty buffer.");

        T result = _buffer[_front];
        _buffer[_front] = default!; // Zap the front element.
        _front          = nextSlot(_front);

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>Returns elements in oldest to newest order. </summary>
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = _front; i != _back; i = nextSlot(i))
        {
            yield return _buffer[i];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator(); // Implement in terms of the typesafe enumerator.
    }

    int nextSlot(int slot)
    {
        return (slot + 1) % _buffer.Length;
    }

    int _front;
    int _back;

    /// <summary>The underlying buffer. This has a length one greater than the actual capacity.</summary>
    readonly T[] _buffer;
}


[ADDENDUM]
The above code is something we've been using since around .Net 3.5. At   that time, it was somewhat faster than using a Queue<T>. However things have improved in later .NET versions.
I benchmarked a comparison between the CircularBuffer above and a simple extension method on Queue<T> to provide the same function as CircularBuffer.Add():
public static class QueueExt
{
    public static void Add<T>(this Queue<T> self, T item, int limit)
    {
        if (self.Count >= limit) // Consider throwing if self.Count > limit.
            self.Dequeue();

        self.Enqueue(item);
    }
}

The (somewhat simplistic) benchmark code for the test was:
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Jobs;

namespace TestQueue;

[MemoryDiagnoser]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net48)]
[SimpleJob(RuntimeMoniker.Net80)]
public class UnderTest
{
    [Benchmark]
    public void ViaQueue()
    {
        _queue.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++)
        {
            _queue.Add(i, 1000);
        }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void ViaCircularArray()
    {
        _buffer.Empty();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++)
        {
            _buffer.Add(i);
        }
    }

    static readonly Queue<double> _queue = new Queue<double>(1000);

    static readonly CircularBuffer<double> _buffer = new CircularBuffer<double>(1000);
}

The results on my system:
| Method           | Runtime            | Mean     | Error   | StdDev  |
|----------------- |------------------- |---------:|--------:|--------:|
| ViaQueue         | .NET 8.0           | 220.5 us | 1.35 us | 1.12 us |
| ViaCircularArray | .NET 8.0           | 380.1 us | 1.67 us | 1.56 us |
| ViaQueue         | .NET Framework 4.8 | 403.6 us | 7.87 us | 7.36 us |
| ViaCircularArray | .NET Framework 4.8 | 390.5 us | 2.43 us | 2.15 us |

For .NET 4.8, the CircularArray is marginally faster. However for .NET 8.0 the Queue<T> is significantly faster.
So I would actually recommend that you use the built-in Queue<T> instead (with an appropriate front end).
The only drawback of Queue<T> is that you can't access its internal Capacity so you would have to pass the limit around - or you could just wrap it in a class that includes the capacity.

Or store the front index and the size so that you don't need an extra element

Yey! thats amazing, and I compared the performance over my old array copy method and its 20x faster, thanks a lot, that worked perfectly !

With doubles it's not a problem, but if (and I am aware that wasn't the question, just a 'heads-up' for people having the same problem) you are going to use this with T : IDisposable, you should probably add a means to dispose of evicted items.

Also be aware that this is not at all thread safe.

@Fildor Of course. The default for most collections (list, array) is that they are not threadsafe. One should assume that something is not threadsafe unless it is explicitly documented as being so.

@MatthewWatson Agreed. Just felt like pointing it out to OP couldn't hurt.

Why not just use a Queue and just dequeue when it gets too large?

Good points, thanks for the clarification, threading safety is not an issue here, the values are added and then read on the same thread, but I can work around using a lock for when enumerating I guess, otherwise that might return garbage...

@Charlieface I initially thought it would render the same performance as a List, but I just tested it with Benchmarkdotnet and I was totally wrong, its performance and allocation is the same as the provided solution, barely any difference

@totalZero Yeah, you can use a Queue - the only real difference is the front end. A Queue does in fact use a Circular Buffer/Array as its implementation.

@totalZero Less code though, which was my point.

@Charlieface And Queue<T> is actually significantly faster on .NET 8 (see my addendum above).
